# rewrite nginx subdirectories to local ports

Tags: node.js, nginx, url-rewriting

Hi i´m trying to host several sites on one server using nginx. Therefore i want to do the following:

calling www.domainname.com/site1

shall forward to http://localhost:9800

calling www.domainname.com/site2

shall forward to http:/localhost:9801

the local sites are hosted by nodejs with express, so rewriting the paths are necessary.

What i´ve done so far is the this:

```
location /site1 {

rewrite ^/site1/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9800;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

}

but this only works partly: The stylesheets etc. will not loaded and trying to call

www.domainname.com/site/login

is not working.

Can someone help me writing the correct rewrite ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use subdomains instead

Comment: I know i can do that but i want to know if it is possible to rewrite the uri

Comment: Links to assets generated by your framework (express), so it has to generate right links.

Comment: Rewrite will not help. You need to change generated html/css/js. Though there is modules to do that, it practically impossible to do this right.